# My Strapi admin panel is now showing loading status indefinitely on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, networking, strapi

This was not the case a few days ago, yesterday this randomly occurred after some changes were made as I had added a significant number of new Fields attributes to a specific Collection Type...

Ever since, my Strapi CMS NodeJS backend is randomly not loading anymore on my localhost, it shows an infinite loading status...

When I first go to my localhost:1337 this is what I get, it all works as it has been and has loaded properly:
[image: localhost:1337]

However, when I click "Open the administration" button to access the Strapi admin panel I get directed to "http://localhost/admin" and get the following:
[image]

When I click on the admin error in the Network tab, it shows the following:
[image]

Normally, the "Open the administration" tab would redirect me to http://localhost:1337/admin however clearly this time it did not.

Now I try to access http://localhost:1337/admin and ***this is where I receive the seemingly infinite loading error...***

[image: My Strapi admin panel]

The first (failed) fetch error (above the preflight error, as this is causing the preflight error), shows:

[image: infinite loading error]

My server.js file is as follows:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  cron: { enabled: true },
  url: env('URL', 'http://localhost'),


  admin: {
    auth: {
      secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET', '9bf8cc74ab83590b280df0851beaec60'),
    },
  },
});
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Strapi-Backend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "The Strapi backend of a JAMstack e-commerce platform built for a Udemy course.",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "strapi": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-admin": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-connector-mongoose": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-graphql": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-provider-email-sendgrid": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-utils": "3.6.8",
    "stripe": "^8.135.0"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "Zachary Reece"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "5e0b8d89-62ac-4e4e-995b-08644071605b"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `server.js` and try:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => {
  const port = env('PORT', '1337');
  const host = env('HOST', '0.0.0.0');
  const url = env('URL', `http://localhost${port !== '80' ? ':'+port : ''}`);
  const adminAuthSecret = env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET', '9bf8cc74ab83590b280df0851beaec60');
  
  return {
    host, port, url,
    cron: { enabled: true },
    cors: { enabled: true, origin: ['*'] },
    admin: {
      auth: { secret: adminAuthSecret },
    }
  }
};
```